# Image detection with Google Vison and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I'm using Node JS to call Google Vision Cloud API. It's working fine but I can't understand how to process the returned object.

```
clinet.textDetection(fileName).then(response => {

    console.log(response);
    console.log(Type(response));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

    // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.responses));
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.fullTextAnnotation));
    // console.log("fullTextAnnotation: " + response.fullTextAnnotation);
    // var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);
    // console.log(jsonObj.key);

}).catch(err => { console.error(err); });
```

Any clue? I have to read **fullTextAnnotation.text** key. All the sample I tried (and left on the code sample are not working [for instance I'm getting undefined]

This is the execution output:

```
[04/12/2017 15:41:53.780] [LOG]   [ { faceAnnotations: [],
    landmarkAnnotations: [],
    logoAnnotations: [],
    labelAnnotations: [],
    textAnnotations: 
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ],
    safeSearchAnnotation: null,
    imagePropertiesAnnotation: null,
    error: null,
    cropHintsAnnotation: null,
    fullTextAnnotation: 
     { pages: [Array],
       text: 'Stefano Vecchier\nSystem Administrator\nstefano.vecchier@domino.it\nM +39 392 93 26 453\n' },
    webDetection: null } ]
[04/12/2017 15:41:53.782] [LOG]   [Function: Array]
[04/12/2017 15:41:53.782] [LOG]   [{"faceAnnotations":[],"landmarkAnnotations":[],"logoAnnotations":[],"labelAnnotations":[],"textAnnotations":[{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"sq","description":"Stefano Vecchier\nSystem Administrator\nstefano.vecchier@domino.it\nM +39 392 93 26 453\n","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":113},{"x":1007,"y":113},{"x":1007,"y":257},{"x":616,"y":257}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"Stefano","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":116},{"x":730,"y":115},{"x":730,"y":138},{"x":616,"y":139}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"Vecchier","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":740,"y":114},{"x":870,"y":113},{"x":870,"y":137},{"x":740,"y":138}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"System","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":155},{"x":726,"y":153},{"x":726,"y":182},{"x":616,"y":184}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"Administrator","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":736,"y":153},{"x":943,"y":150},{"x":943,"y":175},{"x":736,"y":178}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"stefano.vecchier@domino.it","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":617,"y":195},{"x":1007,"y":190},{"x":1007,"y":216},{"x":617,"y":221}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"M","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":618,"y":236},{"x":640,"y":236},{"x":640,"y":257},{"x":618,"y":257}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"+39","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":654,"y":235},{"x":702,"y":234},{"x":702,"y":255},{"x":654,"y":256}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"392","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":712,"y":234},{"x":759,"y":233},{"x":759,"y":255},{"x":712,"y":256}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"93","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":770,"y":234},{"x":801,"y":234},{"x":801,"y":256},{"x":770,"y":256}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"26","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":812,"y":233},{"x":843,"y":233},{"x":843,"y":255},{"x":812,"y":255}]}},{"locations":[],"properties":[],"mid":"","locale":"","description":"453","score":0,"confidence":0,"topicality":0,"boundingPoly":{"vertices":[{"x":854,"y":232},{"x":902,"y":231},{"x":902,"y":253},{"x":854,"y":254}]}}],"safeSearchAnnotation":null,"imagePropertiesAnnotation":null,"error":null,"cropHintsAnnotation":null,"fullTextAnnotation":{"pages":[{"blocks":[{"paragraphs":[{"words":[{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":116},{"x":630,"y":116},{"x":630,"y":139},{"x":616,"y":139}]},"text":"S"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":632,"y":116},{"x":646,"y":116},{"x":646,"y":139},{"x":632,"y":139}]},"text":"t"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":648,"y":122},{"x":663,"y":122},{"x":663,"y":139},{"x":648,"y":139}]},"text":"e"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":665,"y":115},{"x":674,"y":115},{"x":674,"y":138},{"x":665,"y":138}]},"text":"f"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":676,"y":121},{"x":691,"y":121},{"x":691,"y":138},{"x":676,"y":138}]},"text":"a"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":695,"y":121},{"x":710,"y":121},{"x":710,"y":138},{"x":695,"y":138}]},"text":"n"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":714,"y":121},{"x":730,"y":121},{"x":730,"y":138},{"x":714,"y":138}]},"text":"o"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":116},{"x":730,"y":115},{"x":730,"y":138},{"x":616,"y":139}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":740,"y":114},{"x":759,"y":114},{"x":759,"y":138},{"x":740,"y":138}]},"text":"V"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":761,"y":120},{"x":775,"y":120},{"x":775,"y":137},{"x":761,"y":137}]},"text":"e"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":778,"y":120},{"x":794,"y":120},{"x":794,"y":137},{"x":778,"y":137}]},"text":"c"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":796,"y":120},{"x":812,"y":120},{"x":812,"y":137},{"x":796,"y":137}]},"text":"c"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":815,"y":113},{"x":830,"y":113},{"x":830,"y":136},{"x":815,"y":136}]},"text":"h"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":833,"y":113},{"x":838,"y":113},{"x":838,"y":136},{"x":833,"y":136}]},"text":"i"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":841,"y":120},{"x":855,"y":120},{"x":855,"y":136},{"x":841,"y":136}]},"text":"e"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"EOL_SURE_SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":857,"y":119},{"x":870,"y":119},{"x":870,"y":135},{"x":857,"y":135}]},"text":"r"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"fr","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":740,"y":114},{"x":870,"y":113},{"x":870,"y":137},{"x":740,"y":138}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":155},{"x":633,"y":155},{"x":633,"y":184},{"x":616,"y":184}]},"text":"S"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":635,"y":155},{"x":653,"y":155},{"x":653,"y":184},{"x":635,"y":184}]},"text":"y"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":654,"y":156},{"x":666,"y":156},{"x":666,"y":177},{"x":654,"y":177}]},"text":"s"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":668,"y":156},{"x":680,"y":156},{"x":680,"y":177},{"x":668,"y":177}]},"text":"t"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":681,"y":160},{"x":697,"y":160},{"x":697,"y":177},{"x":681,"y":177}]},"text":"e"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":699,"y":160},{"x":726,"y":160},{"x":726,"y":177},{"x":699,"y":177}]},"text":"m"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":155},{"x":726,"y":153},{"x":726,"y":182},{"x":616,"y":184}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":736,"y":154},{"x":757,"y":154},{"x":757,"y":176},{"x":736,"y":176}]},"text":"A"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":758,"y":154},{"x":776,"y":154},{"x":776,"y":178},{"x":758,"y":178}]},"text":"d"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":779,"y":158},{"x":804,"y":158},{"x":804,"y":175},{"x":779,"y":175}]},"text":"m"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":808,"y":152},{"x":812,"y":152},{"x":812,"y":175},{"x":808,"y":175}]},"text":"i"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":815,"y":158},{"x":832,"y":158},{"x":832,"y":175},{"x":815,"y":175}]},"text":"n"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":834,"y":153},{"x":840,"y":153},{"x":840,"y":175},{"x":834,"y":175}]},"text":"i"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":842,"y":153},{"x":855,"y":153},{"x":855,"y":176},{"x":842,"y":176}]},"text":"s"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":857,"y":153},{"x":870,"y":153},{"x":870,"y":176},{"x":857,"y":176}]},"text":"t"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":870,"y":157},{"x":883,"y":157},{"x":883,"y":174},{"x":870,"y":174}]},"text":"r"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":883,"y":158},{"x":900,"y":158},{"x":900,"y":176},{"x":883,"y":176}]},"text":"a"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":900,"y":154},{"x":914,"y":154},{"x":914,"y":176},{"x":900,"y":176}]},"text":"t"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":916,"y":153},{"x":930,"y":153},{"x":930,"y":175},{"x":916,"y":175}]},"text":"o"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"EOL_SURE_SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":932,"y":157},{"x":943,"y":157},{"x":943,"y":175},{"x":932,"y":175}]},"text":"r"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":736,"y":153},{"x":943,"y":150},{"x":943,"y":175},{"x":736,"y":178}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":617,"y":198},{"x":627,"y":198},{"x":627,"y":218},{"x":617,"y":218}]},"text":"s"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":629,"y":198},{"x":640,"y":198},{"x":640,"y":218},{"x":629,"y":218}]},"text":"t"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":643,"y":201},{"x":657,"y":201},{"x":657,"y":218},{"x":643,"y":218}]},"text":"e"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":659,"y":194},{"x":668,"y":194},{"x":668,"y":217},{"x":659,"y":217}]},"text":"f"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":669,"y":200},{"x":683,"y":200},{"x":683,"y":217},{"x":669,"y":217}]},"text":"a"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":686,"y":200},{"x":701,"y":200},{"x":701,"y":217},{"x":686,"y":217}]},"text":"n"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":703,"y":200},{"x":719,"y":200},{"x":719,"y":217},{"x":703,"y":217}]},"text":"o"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":723,"y":200},{"x":732,"y":200},{"x":732,"y":217},{"x":723,"y":217}]},"text":"."},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":734,"y":199},{"x":743,"y":199},{"x":743,"y":216},{"x":734,"y":216}]},"text":"v"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":746,"y":199},{"x":761,"y":199},{"x":761,"y":216},{"x":746,"y":216}]},"text":"e"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":763,"y":199},{"x":777,"y":199},{"x":777,"y":216},{"x":763,"y":216}]},"text":"c"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":781,"y":199},{"x":794,"y":199},{"x":794,"y":216},{"x":781,"y":216}]},"text":"c"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":798,"y":192},{"x":812,"y":192},{"x":812,"y":215},{"x":798,"y":215}]},"text":"h"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":816,"y":192},{"x":819,"y":192},{"x":819,"y":215},{"x":816,"y":215}]},"text":"i"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":823,"y":198},{"x":837,"y":198},{"x":837,"y":215},{"x":823,"y":215}]},"text":"e"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":840,"y":198},{"x":848,"y":198},{"x":848,"y":215},{"x":840,"y":215}]},"text":"r"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":850,"y":194},{"x":872,"y":194},{"x":872,"y":218},{"x":850,"y":218}]},"text":"@"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":876,"y":197},{"x":892,"y":197},{"x":892,"y":214},{"x":876,"y":214}]},"text":"d"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":894,"y":197},{"x":911,"y":197},{"x":911,"y":214},{"x":894,"y":214}]},"text":"o"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":913,"y":197},{"x":937,"y":197},{"x":937,"y":214},{"x":913,"y":214}]},"text":"m"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":940,"y":191},{"x":944,"y":191},{"x":944,"y":214},{"x":940,"y":214}]},"text":"i"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":948,"y":196},{"x":963,"y":196},{"x":963,"y":214},{"x":948,"y":214}]},"text":"n"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":965,"y":196},{"x":980,"y":196},{"x":980,"y":214},{"x":965,"y":214}]},"text":"o"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":985,"y":210},{"x":988,"y":210},{"x":988,"y":214},{"x":985,"y":214}]},"text":"."},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":992,"y":191},{"x":998,"y":191},{"x":998,"y":214},{"x":992,"y":214}]},"text":"i"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"EOL_SURE_SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":1000,"y":191},{"x":1007,"y":191},{"x":1007,"y":214},{"x":1000,"y":214}]},"text":"t"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":617,"y":195},{"x":1007,"y":190},{"x":1007,"y":216},{"x":617,"y":221}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":618,"y":236},{"x":640,"y":236},{"x":640,"y":257},{"x":618,"y":257}]},"text":"M"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":618,"y":236},{"x":640,"y":236},{"x":640,"y":257},{"x":618,"y":257}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":654,"y":241},{"x":669,"y":241},{"x":669,"y":255},{"x":654,"y":255}]},"text":"+"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":671,"y":235},{"x":685,"y":235},{"x":685,"y":256},{"x":671,"y":256}]},"text":"3"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":688,"y":235},{"x":702,"y":235},{"x":702,"y":256},{"x":688,"y":256}]},"text":"9"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":654,"y":235},{"x":702,"y":234},{"x":702,"y":255},{"x":654,"y":256}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":712,"y":234},{"x":726,"y":234},{"x":726,"y":256},{"x":712,"y":256}]},"text":"3"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":729,"y":234},{"x":743,"y":234},{"x":743,"y":256},{"x":729,"y":256}]},"text":"9"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":746,"y":234},{"x":759,"y":234},{"x":759,"y":256},{"x":746,"y":256}]},"text":"2"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":712,"y":234},{"x":759,"y":233},{"x":759,"y":255},{"x":712,"y":256}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":770,"y":234},{"x":784,"y":234},{"x":784,"y":256},{"x":770,"y":256}]},"text":"9"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":787,"y":233},{"x":801,"y":233},{"x":801,"y":255},{"x":787,"y":255}]},"text":"3"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":770,"y":234},{"x":801,"y":234},{"x":801,"y":256},{"x":770,"y":256}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":812,"y":233},{"x":826,"y":233},{"x":826,"y":255},{"x":812,"y":255}]},"text":"2"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":829,"y":233},{"x":843,"y":233},{"x":843,"y":255},{"x":829,"y":255}]},"text":"6"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":812,"y":233},{"x":843,"y":233},{"x":843,"y":255},{"x":812,"y":255}]}},{"symbols":[{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":854,"y":232},{"x":868,"y":232},{"x":868,"y":253},{"x":854,"y":253}]},"text":"4"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":871,"y":232},{"x":885,"y":232},{"x":885,"y":254},{"x":871,"y":254}]},"text":"5"},{"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":{"type":"EOL_SURE_SPACE","isPrefix":false}},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":888,"y":232},{"x":902,"y":232},{"x":902,"y":254},{"x":888,"y":254}]},"text":"3"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"en","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":854,"y":232},{"x":902,"y":231},{"x":902,"y":253},{"x":854,"y":254}]}}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":113},{"x":1007,"y":113},{"x":1007,"y":257},{"x":616,"y":257}]}}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"boundingBox":{"vertices":[{"x":616,"y":113},{"x":1007,"y":113},{"x":1007,"y":257},{"x":616,"y":257}]},"blockType":"TEXT"}],"property":{"detectedLanguages":[{"languageCode":"sq","confidence":0}],"detectedBreak":null},"width":1280,"height":722}],"text":"Stefano Vecchier\nSystem Administrator\nstefano.vecchier@domino.it\nM +39 392 93 26 453\n"},"webDetection":null}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer my question:

```
const fullTextAnnotation = response[0].fullTextAnnotation;
console.log(fullTextAnnotation.text);
```